# Google Drive not gzipping responce

Tags: windows-phone-8, google-drive-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm writing an SDK for Windows Phone to interact with Google Drive and I cannot get the servers to return a gzipped response. I have followed the brief mentioning of it [here in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/performance) as you can see from my requests, but I still only get the raw data:

Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: my program (gzip)
Authorization: Bearer [removed]
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: www.googleapis.com
If-None-Match: "PA40KOhMf9e-1Hypww_TkG8doNA/jgiBh3LdSV9a9DAu8kcM87C_SgA"
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 06:31:47 GMT
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 06:31:47 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
ETag: "PA40KOhMf9e-1Hypww_TkG8doNA/P9KtUv7cYy7pQSattesAaw0ejBM"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 215811
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
```

Both of the above were captured using Fiddler.

Code for creating and using the HttpClient, I originally also included the deflate method as well, but removed it when the example Google provided did not include it:

```
HttpClientHandler Handler = new HttpClientHandler();

if (Handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
{
    Handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
}

HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(Handler);
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token.AccessToken);
if (Handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
{
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "my program (gzip)" /*"DriveClient (gzip)"*/);
}

HttpResponseMessage Responce = await DriveAuthorisation.DriveHttpClient.GetAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/");
```

Thanks!

Comment: What API are you using for creating the Request? Did you look at the new Microsoft.Net.Http and Microsoft.Bcl.Compression? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/06/portable-compression-and-httpclient-working-together.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that earlier and will look over it again. I have included a simplified version of my calling code in the original question.

Comment: Sorry, not related to your question, but I'm curious, why not use the Authorization header directly. e.g. DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthorizationHeaderValue("bearer",Token.AccessToken); ?

Comment: Your request had the Accept-Encoding header with appropriate value but the server ignored it.  Are you sure the server you are connecting to supports GZip?